# Angular: Combine array objects and combine values

Tags: arrays, angularjs, merge

I'm retrieving data with http.get.
This provides me with an array of objects like below:

```
[{
    "id”:12345,
    "resource_state":2,
    "external_id”:”abscdgrft”,
    "upload_id”:1234567,
    "athlete":{
        "id”:123456,
        "resource_state":2,
        "firstname”:”testname”,
        "lastname”:”testlastname”,
        "profile_medium”:”image/athlete/medium.png",
        "profile":"image/athlete/large.png",
        "city”:”testcity”,
        "state”:”teststate”,
        …
    },
    "name”:”test name“,
    "distance":87223.1,
    "moving_time":11026,
    "elapsed_time":11173,
    "total_elevation_gain":682.3,
    …
}]
```

I would like to combine all those object based on the athlete.firstname + athlete.lastname.

So for example all objects with athlete first name Jim and last name Donalds I want to be combined in one object, the same goes for all the other names.

When combining the objects based on the full name, values like "distance", "moving_time", "elapsed_time" and "total_elevation_gain" needs to be summed.

I tried using the code below but the problem is that I can't get it to work with multiple values like I mention above.

This is working only with one value, distance for example:

```
var obj = {}; // Initialize the object

angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
    if (value.start_date > firstdayOfWeek && value.start_date < lastdayOfWeek) {
        if (obj[value.athlete.firstname + ' ' + value.athlete.lastname]) { // If already exists
            obj[value.athlete.firstname + ' ' + value.athlete.lastname] += value.distance; // Add value to previous value
        } else {
            obj[value.athlete.firstname + ' ' + value.athlete.lastname] = value.distance; // Add in object
        }
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
});
console.log(obj); // Result
```

When I modify it like this it is not working anymore.

```
var obj = {};

            angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {

                //console.log(value);

                if (value.start_date > startOfLastWeek && value.start_date < endOfLastWeek) {

                    //console.log(value);

                    if (obj[value.athlete.firstname + ' ' + value.athlete.lastname]) { // If already exists
                        obj[value.athlete.firstname + ' ' + value.athlete.lastname] += { 
                            "profile" : value.athlete.profile,
                            "distance" : value.distance,
                            "moving_time" : value.moving_time,
                            "elapsed_time" : value.elapsed_time,
                            "total_elevation_gain" : value.total_elevation_gain,
                        }; // Add value to previous value
                    } else {
                        obj[value.athlete.firstname + ' ' + value.athlete.lastname] = { 
                            "profile" : value.athlete.profile,
                            "distance" : value.distance,
                            "moving_time" : value.moving_time,
                            "elapsed_time" : value.elapsed_time,
                            "total_elevation_gain" : value.total_elevation_gain, 
                        }; // Add in object             
                    }
                } else {
                    //do nothing
                }
            });

            console.log(obj); // Result
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show us what you have done to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add item by item... You can't add all with += { ... }:

```
var obj = {};

        angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {

            //console.log(value);

            if (value.start_date > startOfLastWeek && value.start_date < endOfLastWeek) {

                //console.log(value);

                if (obj[value.athlete.firstname + ' ' + value.athlete.lastname]) { // If already exists
                    var aux = obj[value.athlete.firstname + ' ' + value.athlete.lastname];
aux.profile  += value.athlete.profile;
aux.distance += value.distance;
...
                } else {
                    obj[value.athlete.firstname + ' ' + value.athlete.lastname] = { 
                        "profile" : value.athlete.profile,
                        "distance" : value.distance,
                        "moving_time" : value.moving_time,
                        "elapsed_time" : value.elapsed_time,
                        "total_elevation_gain" : value.total_elevation_gain, 
                    }; // Add in object             
                }
            } else {
                //do nothing
            }
        });

        console.log(obj); // Result
```

Comment: gives me error SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'aux'. Expected a ':' following the property name 'var'. in this line: var aux = obj[value.athlete.firstname + ' ' + value.athlete.lastname];

Comment: I found the fix for my previous comment only for some reason my ng-repeat list ignores limitto and shows the complete array with your solution.

Comment: Your foreach is stepping on the new "obj" object? You can to create a filter with your function, something like "myGroupFilter", and put on ng-repeat pipe: data | myGroupFilter | limit ...

Answer (score 0):

Use underscore or lodash [`groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy), [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map) and [`reduce`](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce)

with lodash:

```
_.chain(myArr).map(function(o) {
   return {
       fullname: o.athlete.firstname + ' ' + o.athlete.lastname,
       distance: o.distance,
       moving_time: o.moving_time,
       elapsed_time: o.elapsed_time,
       total_elevation_gain: o.total_elevation_gain
   }

}).groupBy(function(o) {
   return o.fullaname
}).map(function(d, fullname) {

   var totals =  _.reduce(d, function(result, run, n) {
      result.moving_time +=  run.moving_time | 0
      result.elapsed_time +=  run.elapsed_time | 0
      result.total_elevation_gain +=  run.total_elevation_gain | 0   
      return result     
   }, {
      moving_time: 0,
      elapsed_time: 0,
      total_elevation_gain: 0
   })

   totals.fullname = fullname 

   return totals

})
```

Comment: lodash give me all kind off ionic project errors, so lodash is not an option for me.

Comment: @user1242574 I'm using lodash with ionic just fine. What kind of errors you are getting? How do you plug it in ?

Comment: Failed to instantiate module lodash due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'lodash' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: I have added <script src="lodash.js"></script> and added 'lodash' module

Comment: @user1242574 lodash is not angular module. if you want to use it as angular module just add  `angular.module('myModule').value('_',_)`

Comment: I have added it like this var app = angular.module(‘MyApp’, ['ionic', ‘lodash’, …’])

Comment: @user1242574 That is not what I am talking about.  remove `lodash` from list of dependencies. Use either `_` directly, or add snippet from my previous comment and use `_` dependency ( i e `.controller($scope, _,...)`)